# Rails-api gem pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

Is there a way to add JSON pagination using the rails-api gem API?

I want to be able to fetch the first 50 users, then on another call start at the 50th user and get 50 more.

Something like this:
`url.com/api/v1/users?start=50`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Will Paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate), you can also specify how many item you want to show.

You can also follow [Rails Cast tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/51-will-paginate) on how to use will paginate

Answer (score 5):

you Can use "api-pagination" gem for add JSON pagination .

for more info go through with this :
https://github.com/davidcelis/api-pagination